# Removing all "H" within the strings, EXCEPT the ones including "CH"

Tags: r, regex, text-mining, data-cleaning

I am trying to remove all "H" within the strings, EXCEPT the ones including "CH" in the following example:

```
strings <- c("Cash","Wishes","Chain","Chip","Check")
```

I found that the code below remove only  "H"

```
data<- gsub("H", "", strings)
```

Comment: Just a doodle: `gsub("my_desired_combination_", "Ch", gsub("h", "", gsub("Ch", "my_desired_combination_", strings)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a negative look-behind.

```
gsub("(?<!c)h", "", strings, perl=TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
```